# Elasticseach completion suggester return suggestions from specific index type

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, autocomplete

Current stack involves **node.js v0.12.7** running with **elasticsearch-js >=1.1.0** with the **Elasticsearch 1.7 API**.

My current elasticsearch settings is mapped to have 1 index with 2 types:

```
elasticsearch.client.indices.create({
      index: 'randomindex',
      body: {
        "settings": {
          "analysis": {
            "filter": {
              "autocomplete_filter": {
                "type": "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
              }
            },
            "analyzer": {
              "autocomplete": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "autocomplete_filter"
                ]
              },
              "my_english": {
                "type":      "english",
                "stopwords": "_english_"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        'mappings': {
          'countries': {
            'properties': {
              'country': {
                'type': 'string',
                'fields': {
                  "autocomplete": { "type": "string", "index_analyzer": "autocomplete", "search_analyzer": "my_english" }
                }
              },
              "suggest_countries": {
                "type": "completion",
                "index_analyzer": "simple",
                "search_analyzer": "simple",
                "payloads": true
              }
            }
          },
          'some_other_type': {
            'properties': {
              "field_1": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "field_2": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "suggest_some_other_field": {
                "type": "completion",
                "index_analyzer": "simple",
                "search_analyzer": "simple",
                "payloads": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

I have then populated both suggestion fields with relevant "input", "output" and "payload" fields.

I would like to specify a particular index type to return suggestions from but it is throwing errors when I do this:

```
elasticsearch.clients.suggest({
    index: "randomindex",
    type: "countries",
    body: {
      "suggest": {
        text: query,
        completion: {
          "field": "suggest_countries"
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Is there any way I could specify / refer to a specific type in the .suggest method?

Comment: Please share the error ES is throwing.

Comment: There is no error when I run it on node. it just returns an empty options array in the response object. However, when I try to reach the `/randomindex/countries/_suggest` endpoint via a client like google Chrome's Sense extension, I pass something like `{"suggest_countries":{"text":"a","completion":{"field":"suggest_countries"}}}` and it throws an error like `MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Unknown field name[text], must be one of [output, context, input, weight, payload]];`.

Comment: I can ensure that I have populated the `suggest_countries` field correctly in the `autocomplete_countries` type because I have checked on Sense against the endpoint `/randomindex/countries/_search` and everything seems to be there.

Comment: You need to remove `countries` from the path and only have `/randomindex/_suggest`. As you can [see in the source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/8275ab497b349ed2df375770a151e65c90dd9410/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/suggest/RestSuggestAction.java#L69-L72), you either need to call `/_suggest` or `/index/_suggest` without type information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your call without `type` parameter

```
elasticsearch.clients.suggest({
    index: "randomindex",
    body: {
      "suggest": {
        text: query,
        completion: {
          "field": "suggest_countries"
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

See the official documentation for the [`client.suggest()` call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-suggest), there is no `type` parameter available.